# Swagger: take one or more values from enum

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

I am writing an OpenAPI (Swagger) definition where a query parameter can take none, or N values, like this:

```
/path?sort=field1,field2
```

How can I write this in OpenAPI YAML?

I tried the following, but it does not produce the expected result:

```yaml
- name: sort
  in: query
  schema:
    type: string
    enum: [field1,field2,field3]
  allowEmptyValue: true
  required: false
  description: Sort the results by attributes. (See http://jsonapi.org/format/1.1/#fetching-sorting)
```

Comment: So is it "one or more values" (e.g. if present, must have at least 1 value) or "none or n values" (e.g. may be present without a value, as in `?sort`)?

Comment: It's "none or more". That's why `allowEmptyValue: true` is present. `?sort=`, `?sort=field1`, `?sort=field1,field2` are valid path.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A query parameter containing a **comma-separated list of values** is defined as an **array**. If the values are predefined, then it's an **array of enum**.

By default, an array may have any number of items, which matches your "none or more" requirement. If needed, you can restrict the number of items using `minItems` and `maxItems`, and optionally enforce `uniqueItems: true`.

#### OpenAPI 2.0

The parameter definition would look as follows. `collectionFormat: csv` indicates that the values are comma-separated, but this is the default format so it can be omitted.

```yaml
      parameters:
        - name: sort
          in: query
          type: array  # <-----
          items:
            type: string
            enum: [field1, field2, field3]
          collectionFormat: csv  # <-----
          required: false
          description: Sort the results by attributes. (See http://jsonapi.org/format/1.1/#fetching-sorting)
```

#### OpenAPI 3.x

`collectionFormat: csv` from OpenAPI 2.0 has been replaced with `style: form` + `explode: false`. `style: form` is the default style for query parameters, so it can be omitted.

```yaml
      parameters:
        - name: sort
          in: query
          schema:
            type: array  # <-----
            items:
              type: string
              enum: [field1, field2, field3]
          required: false
          description: Sort the results by attributes. (See http://jsonapi.org/format/1.1/#fetching-sorting)
          explode: false  # <-----
```

I think there's no need for `allowEmptyValue`, because an empty array will be effectively an empty value in this scenario. Moreover, `allowEmptyValue` is [not recommended](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/releases/tag/3.0.2) for use since OpenAPI 3.0.2 "as it will be removed in a future version."

Comment: Thanks, I am gonna give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for great answer. Unfortunately falls foul of https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/3345 for me :\

Comment: @Helen: Does swagger support enums with key value pairs?