# Query parameter with comma-separated strings in Swagger returns structural error

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, openapi

I am trying to define a query parameter in Swagger with comma-separated strings from a predefined set of items like `?fruits=Apples,Oranges,Bananas` but I get the following error from the swagger editor

> should NOT have additional properties   additionalProperty: style,
>   explode

What I am trying in the Swagger Editor is:

```
    - in: query
      name: fruits
      style: form
      explode: true
      required: false
      description: Filter by fruits
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
        enum:
          - Apples
          - Oranges
          - Bananas
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger: take one or more values from enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50538138/swagger-take-one-or-more-values-from-enum)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`style` and `explode` are OpenAPI 3.0 keywords. But you seem to be using OpenAPI 2.0, which uses [`collectionFormat`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#user-content-parametercollectionformat) instead. In this case you need `collectionFormat: csv` (it's the default option and can be omitted).

Comment: For those using OpenAPI 3.0, the equivalent combination is `style: form` (default) and `explode: false`