# How to define openAPI parameter combinations?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

how can does the right OpenAPI 3 definition looks like

possible endpoints:

- /tickets (->/tickets?status=* - all Ticket no matter what status)
- /tickets?satus=new
- /tickets?satus=sold
- /tickets?satus=canceled
- /tickets?satus=new,sold
- /tickets?satus=sold,canceled
- /tickets?satus=any_othe_combination

With "enum:" the API only accept ONE parameter, or? Not a combination?
Is it simple "value"?

...
statusparam:

```
 name: status

 in: path

 schema:

    type: string

    value: ['*','new','sold','canceled','some1','some2','some3']

    default: '*'
```

BUT in swagger-ui the value is not checkt - onyl that it exists but i could also use"somethingnotinthelist " - swagger-ui will accept it

Can I use allowEmptyValue: true  instead of *

Thanks for help
rob

Comment: I found allowedValues but swagger UI still let me put in soem other values nor the values ar presentetd like they are when i would use enum
...
      relparam:
         name: relype
         in: query
         description: >-
            filter by relationshiptype
         schema:
            type: string
            allowedValues: ['*','new','sold','canceled','some1','some2','some3'] 
            default: '*'

Comment: seems i mixed up swagger 2.0 and openAPI 3.0 
But still swagger_ui is nor complaining when i enter somesthin different
...
      relparam:
         name: status
         in: query
         type: string
         pattern: '(all|new|sold|canceled|some1|some2|some3)' 
         default: all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swagger: take one or more values from enum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50538138/113116)